# Why did Harry's father emerge before his mother in HP and the Goblet of Fire?

Tags: harry-potter, magic, spells

In Harry Potter book 4 (Goblet of Fire) Harry's wand 'links' with Voldemort's during their duel, and Voldemort's wand begins 'spitting out' each spell it had cast, in reverse order.  This produces false 'ghosts' of people he had killed with [Avada Kedavra](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Avada_Kedavra_Curse).  In the US printing, James Potter appears, followed by Lily.

If the spell order was supposed to be reversed, why did Harry's father's "ghost" emerge before his mother's, since it's repeatedly stated (before and after) that he died first?

Comment: can you add some details here, like which scene, spell, etc? I've read the books but can't place what you mean.

Comment: @Wikis - I assume he meant the linking of the two wands when Harry was dueling Voldermort and V.'s wand emitted the ghosts of all the people it killed in reverse.

Comment: Edited the question for clarity and to make it less likely to be closed.  It's still a pretty simple, googlable question, but now it's at least readable.

Comment: Just a note, that phenomenon is called Priori Incantatem.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

JK Rowling got it wrong. She actually had it right, her editor told her that it was wrong, and she changed it to be the wrong way. This was corrected in later versions.

[The explanation was previously on her official site](http://web.archive.org/web/20070607000652/http://www.jkrowling.com/textonly/en/faq_view.cfm?id=19), but her site has undergone a major rehaul recently. In any case, I tracked down the original quote, and have included it below.

> **At the end of 'Goblet of Fire', in which order should Harry's parents
>   have come out of the wand?**
>
> Lily first, then James. That’s how it appears in my original
>   manuscript but we were under enormous pressure to edit it very fast
>   and my American editor thought that was the wrong way around, and he
>   is so good at catching small errors I changed it without thinking,
>   then realised it had been right in the first place. We were all very
>   sleep-deprived at the time.

Comment: cool. do you have a source for this?

Comment: I took the liberty of adding the source for you.  Feel free to revert if you so desire.

Comment: The cited link no longer works.

Comment: Interestingly, the current US Kindle text replicates the error in the first US printing, in a different location: chapter 36, "The Parting of the Ways".  One sentence reads: "He could see Cedric emerging, see the old man, Bertha Jorkins...his father...his mother...".  We could argue that Harry remembered the people out of order (but only his parents, the rest being consistent).  But it seems likelier that this sentence was consistent with the actual scene in the first printing, and that this remembrance went mistakenly uncorrected when the scene was corrected.